# Soft Shadow Technique using XNA 3.0

Tags: c#, xna, shader, shadow-mapping, xna-3.0

I am working with XNA 3.0 (sigh, I know) and I am working off a tutorial that helps implement a 3d scene with objects where a spot light hits a torus and projects a hard-edged shadow. Now, I want to know where I can find help (tutorial, source code, snippet) to soften said shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be use Percentage Closer Filtering. Basically it works by taking a few shadow map samples. You can start from an [article in GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch11.html).

Comment: Thank you it helped out a lot what we did also is aslo altering the offset of the shadow. It kind of has a lapping effect but it is close enough.